# Uncaught ReferenceError: pivotUtilities is not defined - asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have very limited knowledge of javascript and no Razor knowledge. I am trying to reproduce a working Razor/.net core solution to asp.net and am unable to get the reference to the pivottable.js scripts to work.

Any guidance on how to get past the error would be appreciated.

Thanks,

A snip of my script is as follows:

```
<script>
    var myInvoiceDetails = [];
    var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers; **<-- Errors here.**
    var renderers = $.extend(pivotUtilities.renderers,
        pivotUtilities.plotly_renderers,
        pivotUtilities.export_renderers);
    }
</script>
```

My JS references:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-basic-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="pivot/pivot.js"></script>
    <script src="pivot/plotly_renderers.js"></script>
```

Console error.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qvQi.png)

js directories (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iklv3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    var myInvoiceDetails = [];
        var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;
        var renderers = $.extend(pivotUtilities.renderers,
        pivotUtilities.plotly_renderers,
        pivotUtilities.export_renderers);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working. Am getting the same plus additional errors with calling the myInvoiceDetails as well. 
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: myInvoiceDetails is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (SageAccountsAnalysis.aspx:88:17)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2:29677)